# Why is lists faster than numpy?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Why in this example are lists faster than numpy? numpy is usually considered faster than using lists? But here lists seem to be over 2x faster?

```bash
$ python main.py 
using_list: 1.8105032444000244 seconds
using_numpy: 4.414405345916748 seconds
```

```py
# main.py
import numpy as np
import time

def using_list(N):
    x = [1] * N
    y = [0] * N
    for i in range(1, N):
        y[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (y[i-1] - x[i])

def using_numpy(N):
    x = np.ones(N)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(1, N):
        y[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (y[i-1] - x[i])

def main():
    LOOPS = 100
    N = 100000
    for func in [using_list, using_numpy]:
        t = time.perf_counter()
        for i in range(LOOPS):
            func(N)
        print(f"{func.__name__}: {time.perf_counter() - t} seconds")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Using Python 3.10.

For reference, I have found that using `@njit` from `numba` will dramatically improve my numpy code. But I was wondering why my plain numpy version is so much slower than lists? And is there a way to make my plain numpy version faster without using `numba`.

```bash
using_numba: 0.6930002999997669 seconds
```

```py
from numba import njit

@njit
def using_numba(N):
    x = np.ones(N)
    y = np.zeros(N)
    for i in range(1, N):
        y[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (y[i-1] - x[i])
```

Comment: Because you shouldn't iterate manually with numpy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterating or using indices to access numpy arrays element by element is inefficient (please refer to [Why is for loop on native python list faster than for loop on numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47825514/why-is-for-loop-on-native-python-list-faster-than-for-loop-on-numpy-array)). Consider using numpy's built-in functions or methods to accelerate the loop, which can significantly improve the performance on large arrays:

```
def mechanic_using_numpy(N):
    y = np.empty(N, float)
    y[:1] = 1.0
    y[1:] = 0.5
    y.cumprod(out=y)
    np.subtract(1, y, out=y)
    return y
```

```
>>> mechanic_using_numpy(10)
array([0.        , 0.5       , 0.75      , 0.875     , 0.9375    ,
       0.96875   , 0.984375  , 0.9921875 , 0.99609375, 0.99804688])
>>> np.array(using_list(10))
array([0.        , 0.5       , 0.75      , 0.875     , 0.9375    ,
       0.96875   , 0.984375  , 0.9921875 , 0.99609375, 0.99804688])
```

Benchmark with `N = 100000`:

```
In [_]: %timeit using_numpy(100000)
44.6 ms ± 227 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [_]: %timeit using_list(100000)
14.3 ms ± 38.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [_]: %timeit mechanic_using_numpy(100000)
286 µs ± 875 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to get the benefits from numpy, you need to approach the calculation differently.  Think of it as a global operation on all values rather than an iterative calculation:

For example, this function gives the same result but runs up to 25 times faster than using a list:

```
def using_np(N):
    return 1 - 0.5**(np.arange(N))
```

If you need more speed, you can combine simpler operations (e.g. addition & multiplication instead of exponentiation):

```
def using_np2(N):
    y      = np.ones(N)
    y[0]   = 0
    y[1:] -= np.cumprod(y[1:]/2)
    return y
```

*This one is more than 40 times faster than using a list*

Answer (score 2):

Numpy is fast when it can implicitly parallelize operations. If you didn't have the `y[i-1] -> y[i]` data dependency, you could replace a loop like

```
for i in range(N):
    y[i] = 0.5*x[i]
```

with

```
y = 0.5*x
```

---

Iterating over the elements of an array is no faster than iterating over the elements of a list, and is in fact slightly slower due to the need to convert back and forth between Numpy value types and Python native types.

For example, a list of `float` values is just a list of references. `y[i]` is a reference to a `float` value that exists outside the list. An array with `dtype` of `float64`, however, is just a single binary blob that represents a collection of floating-point values. An operation like `y[i]` has to extract the proper bits then use them to *create* a `float` value to return. A more complicated expression like

```
y[i] = x[i] + 0.5 * (y[i-1] - x[i])
```

needs to extract *three* such values from `x` and `y`, do the same arithmetic you would do with the list approach, then convert the result back to a byte sequence to insert back into `y`.

---

With `y = 0.5*x`, there are no conversions of byte sequences to `float` values, use of `float.__mul__`, or conversions back to bytes sequences. All arithmetic is done internally in Numpy's optimized C code.